# iOS 4.3 and CMYK JPG images

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4

I updated my iPad yesterday from iOS 4.2.1 to iOS 4.3. An application I am working on uses a bunch of JPG images that were exported from Photoshop as CMYK JPG images. In 4.2.1, the images displayed correctly, but in 4.3, they are displayed incorrectly, mostly black.

Are CMYK images not supported? Is this is bug with iOS 4.3? If it matters, I've tried both setting the images directly in Interface Builder as well as setting it via code using `UIImage imageNamed:` and `UIImageView setImage:` methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Apple didn't specifically say they were dropping support for this format in any of their iOS developer documentation, then file a bug report with Apple. They rarely drop support for image, movie, audio, etc... formats.

Comment: I submitted bug report 'Problem ID: 9114865'

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 4.3 your CMYK jpeg image will be mostly black if you load it directly with [UIImage imageNamed:] I solved it in my app simply by converting the image downloaded to JPEG before loading it into the image property:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageFilePath], 1.0)];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That certainly is a good workaround. Not as convenient as specifying the images in Interface Builder, sadly. I ended up having the images re-encoded as RGB. And I'm still holding out hope for the bug I opened with Apple. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work on iOS 5. It will have errors    <Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 32 bits/pixel; 4-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNone; 950 bytes/row.
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageDestinationAddImage image could not be converted to destination format.
ImageIO: <ERROR>  CGImageDestinationFinalize image destination does not have enough images

Answer (score 0):

If someone falls here by Google, just had the same problem.

In iOS 5 everything works great, but in 4.3.x the image is mostly black, just some shadows appear.

ATM, the solution was change the image color palette.